Does a Off-(On)-On switch exist?
I am designing a switchbox to manually control some solenoid valves.
I have been searching for toggle/rocker switches but have not found the exact functionality I am looking for.
I would like to have the valve off when the switch is down, momentarily on when the switch is in the middle and fully on when the switch is all the way up.
Does anyone know if this switch exists or am I out of luck?

What position does the switch go back to after being in the center position?

It would go back to OFF after being momentarily On.

You could try looking at an electronic surplus seller if you are not trying to put this into production. You might be able to find a switch from a 1960s military radar power supply or something. I just remembered I have seen military toggle switches that do something like this, but you have to pull the baton out to lock them into the maintained-on position. Pricey.

what is the reason for such functionality?  ... why wouldn't center off work?

Basically, it would serve our solenoid cycling process better and be a bit more intuitive for the users. My original thinking was to go ON-OFF-(ON) but after talking to some of the end users OFF-(ON)-ON would be ideal. It doesn't look like I will be able to find that functionality so I may just have to stick with my original thinking of ON-OFF-(ON).

If your quantity is high enough, or the need strong enough, you could probably get a switch manufacturer to do a custom one for you.

Your best bet is probably to search for "modular selector switches" as used in industrial control panels. These come with a panel mount selector switch with various options for OFF/ON, ON/OFF/ON, latching and non-latching. NO and NC contact blocks can be mounted to get whatever configuration you require.
Your requirement for OFF/ON (unlatched)/ON (latched) is unusual so you might have to search around or settle for ON (unlatched)/OFF/ON (latched).
All the major industrial component manufacturers supply them: Siemens, A-B, Schneider Electric, RS Pro, Eaton, etc.
